# Keep login credentials throughout webviews on iOS app (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, wkwebview

I'm building an iOS app (swift) that should work like this:

First, there's a WKWebView with a login form.
Below that, there's a button which uses a navigation controller to open a UICollectionView that displays a series of icons, each one for a different service.
Each service opens as a new WebView inside a restrict area (login needed).

I'm trying to unify the login action in the first screen of the app so the user doesn't have to login again every time he opens a new service. The problem is that the login is not kept throughout the app, like a session. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario I would store the login form values in a Preference and pass those login form values to each service invocation.  See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

Comment: The login form is in a web page and all other webviews inside share the same login/password but it's not keeping these values. I'd like to store the web authentication across the webviews inside the app so there would be only one login in the welcome screen for all webviews.

Comment: so fi I am hearing this right then  all the services use the same username/password.  In that case just create a custom form that takes the username/password and send those to login form prior to invoking the service.  You can check what the param are for the form by looking at the source and do a post or get with those params.